# I cant automate input in bash script with a echo "yes" | command

Tags: bash

Why is this not working? I am trying to automate this in bash script but I am still prompted for a yes....

```
echo "yes" | ssh -T git@github.com 
The authenticity of host
   'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established. RSA key
   fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48. Are
   you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Comment: Presumably ssh is trying to read the "yes" directly from the terminal rather than from its stdin.

Comment: Use `expect`. It's a better solution: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107456/bash-script-calls-expect-script-with-master-ssh-connection

Comment: There's probably a command-line option to `ssh` to tell it to accept the key without asking, but I'm not sure what it is. Maybe `StrictHostKeyChecking`?

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts

Comment: Note that the accepted answer to Pumbaa80's link is not actually the recommended answer. Instead, put the fingerprint in your `.ssh/known_hosts` file, so that in future connection attempts, you will only get the warning if the fingerprint changes, which could indicate that some other host is masquerading as `github.com`.

Comment: Did you try searching for the answer to your problem?  https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+automatically+enter+yes

Answer (score 2):

[@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) deserves credit for the crucial pointer: disable option `StrictHostKeyChecking` to suppress the prompt altogether:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T git@github.com
```

Note, however, that:

- suppressing or auto-confirming the authenticity prompt is not recommended for security reasons
- on a given machine, once you've connected to a remote host for the first time and have confirmed the prompt, you will not be prompted again, because that hosts's fingerprint will automatically be saved to configuration file `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

Thus, if feasible, the better option is to save the fingerprints of all potential target hosts to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` or `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` up front, as [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) recommends in a comment.

Note, though, that if a remote host['s hard drive] is *replaced* (e.g., after hardware failure) without transferring its old own-identity fingerprint file, the authentication warning prompt will reappear due to generation of a new fingerprint - unless that new fingerprint is again saved on accessing machines beforehand.

---

As [@Ian Roberts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592139/ian-roberts) points out, the reason that just piping a response via stdin doesn't work is presumably that `ssh` reads the response directly from the terminal.

As [@konsolebox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445221/konsolebox) points out, if you do need to automate interaction with `ssh`, `expect` (see `man expect`) is the right tool for the job, but since this generally involves automating password entry, it comes with security caveats.

Comment: A better way to suppress the prompt is to teach `ssh` that it is, in fact, the correct fingerprint, by adding it to `.ssh/known_hosts`.

Comment: @chepner: Agreed, but that obviously hinges on known the full set of potential target hosts in advance. I've updated my answer and incorporated your hint.

Comment: The script assumes you have received log-in credentials of some kind to any potential target; update `known_hosts` when those credentials are received ;)

Comment: I will concede that this is the correct answer if you are willing to assume that a change in fingerprint is the result of a legitimate change in hardware the remote end (something I myself assume in certain circumstances).

Comment: @chepner: Can you elaborate? (I know little about this). Isn't a fingerprint a randomly generated key pair stored statically in a file pair? How do hardware changes play into this?. As an aside (I'm really out of my depth here): It seems there is an alternative method of fingerprint verification via special DNS resource records (SSHFP), which, I presume, then persistently identifies a given host, even in the event of hardware changes.

Comment: The usual time I notice these warnings is when my company's IT department is deploying replacement machines; they may not be bothering to transfer fingerprints to the new machine, instead just generating new fingerprints. As a rule, though, the purpose is to make you suspicious if you get this warning after you've connected to a host for the first time, so you're defeating that level of security by blindly answer "yes" every time it comes up.

Comment: @chepner: I see - you're talking about replacing _entire machines_. Makes sense. Just added a hint to my answer - let me know if you feel something else must be added/changed.